# archiver.js memory leak inside aws lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-archiver, archiverjs

I'm using [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) to zip a few files in aws lambda. I see that when there is no more disk space to write, archiver still holds(or leaks) some data. I've been trying to do 'archive.close()' or 'archive.destroy()' but I keep getting archive.close/(archive.destroy) is not a function error. Wondering if anyone has run into this or resolved it. Here is how my code looks like:

```
exports.makeZip = function(source, destination) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.info("started zipping from source: %s to destination: %s", source, destination);
        let output, archive;
        try {
            output = fs.createWriteStream(destination);
            archive = archiver('zip');
            output.on('close', function () {
                output.destroy();
                //archive.close();
                console.log("Completed Zipping!");
                resolve();
            });
            output.on('error', function(err) {
                output.destroy();
                //archive.close();
                console.error("something went wrong while zipping! ", err);
                reject(new Error(err));
            });
            archive.on('error', function(err) {
                //archive.close();
                output.destroy();
                console.error("something went wrong while zipping! ", err);
                reject(new Error(err));
            });
            archive.pipe(output);
            archive.directory(source, false);
            archive.finalize();
        } catch (error) {
            if (typeof output !== 'undefined') {
                output.destroy();
            }
            if (typeof archive !== 'undefined') {
                archive.close();
            }
            console.error("Zipping failed. Reason: %s", error.message)
            reject(new Error(error));
        }
    });
};
```

The way I know that this is causing the memory leak because I printed the disk space before and after I remove my files at the beginning and at the end of my Lambda invocation. I see that there is some space that is not cleaned up.

```
Before cleanup
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        8191416 6107036   2067996  75% /
/dev/vdb         1490800   34896   1439520   3% /dev
/dev/vdd          538424  526588         0 100% /tmp
After cleanup
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        8191416 6107036   2067996  75% /
/dev/vdb         1490800   34896   1439520   3% /dev
/dev/vdd          538424   11068    515520   3% /tmp
```